# Perl Try::Tiny stuck in Loop

Tags: perl, try-catch

I am using a Try::Tiny statement to avoid failing if I can't rsh to a host.  But it seems that the rsh is getting retried indefinitely.

In this particular case, Host2 went down, and the code just repeatedly attempted to contact Host2 until I cancelled execution with CTRL+C.  What I am expecting is for Host2 rsh command to fail, and the script to move on to Host3.

Any idea of why this doesn't work and how I could do it differently?

```
@Win_Clients = ("Host1","Host2","Host2");

foreach $Win_Client (@Win_Clients){
    try {
        @mem= rsh ($Win_Client, "wmic memphysical get MaxCapacity");
        print "host=$Win_Client, mem=$mem";
    };
}
```

Comment: Do you need to `rsh` to use `wmic`? Can you not use `/node:host` instead?

Comment: I am not familiar with /node:host.  A quick google search didn't turn anything up.  Do you have a link with more details?

Comment: Try `help wmic`: `/NODE  Servers the alias will operate against.`. E.g. `wmic /node:localhost partition get`

Comment: Unfortunately the host running the script is a linux box, so running it this way is not an option.  I am trying to run a remote command from Linux to a Windows box.

Comment: I think the answer to your problem would therefore lie in 'how does your rsh do it'? Because that's an imported function, not a built in. `Try::Tiny` doesn't seem necessary if your rsh isn't `die`ing.

Comment: Try::Tiny doesn't loop. It calls the block once and only once. I don't believe you are having the problem you claim to be having.

Comment: Turns out the rsh client is an in-house module and the default behavior is to retry indefinitely.  (poor design) After calling out a retry limit, the script will eventually fail after a couple retries.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best solution would be to not use `rsh` to run wmic, and instead use the built in remote access mechanism `/node`

```
C:\Users\ME>wmic /node:localhost memphysical get MaxCapacity
MaxCapacity
4194304


C:\Users\ME>wmic /node:narf memphysical get MaxCapacity
Node - narf
ERROR:
Description = The RPC server is unavailable.
```

And then you won't need to do anything like running `rsh` or `try`. You can simply trap error levels in the 'usual way'. (`$?` in your perl client)

```
C:\Users\ME>wmic /?

[global switches] <command>

The following global switches are available:
/NAMESPACE           Path for the namespace the alias operate against.
/ROLE                Path for the role containing the alias definitions.
/NODE                Servers the alias will operate against.
```

Comment: Unfortunately the host running the script is a linux box, so running it this way is not an option.  I am trying to run a remote command from Linux to a Windows box.

Comment: Are you running an `rshd` on your Windows host then? That's unusual.

Comment: Yes.  I am part of MegaCorp and this is how their automation is implemented with Windows boxes.

Comment: Related point then - why are you using `Try::Tiny` at all? Does your `rsh` function die when it fails? You don't seem to have a `catch` block either, which'd be normal.